# Navigation bar issue on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I recently made a website, and it works fine on all browsers, but on Internet EXplorer, the navigation bar on the gallery sections doesn't render properly, but on the index.html (home page ) it renders fine. The link to the issue page is http://galant-jeans.x10.mx/dyer_galeri.html

Comment: it does not render correctly but renders fine on the home page ? It does not work but it works ? It works fine for me in FF

Comment: Sorry Jon but this is not a valid question.

Comment: Look closely, I lined to the gallery, where the navigation bar doesn't render currently, and I also specified that the issue is with Internet Explorer. The home page renders fine tho.

Comment: If it **doesn't** crash, why does your question title say it does?

Comment: Also [garbage in](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgalant-jeans.x10.mx%2Fdyer_galeri.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2), garbage out.

Comment: @Quentin, all the errors are about the rel attribute, that is used for the lightbox, and the missing alts in images. I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: @JonDujaka — That isn't true. Only most of them are. One of the problems with not caring about certain errors is that they obscure other errors that you might actually care about.

Comment: @Quentin, I really can't find a problem on my Mark Up that might be responsible for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index.html` includes [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/):

```
<script src="./js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>
```

`dyer_galeri.html` does not.

Internet Explorer versions less than 9 do not support unknown elements (such as the [HTML5 semantic elements](http://caniuse.com/html5semantic) you're using) unless JavaScript is used to add support. [Modernizr includes a fix for the problem.](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#html5inie)

**tl;dr**: include Modernizr in your gallery page.

Comment: I really hope this works.
Currently, I can't access cpanel on my hosting account to edit it.
I edited the file ony my computer, and I think it's working, but will test the uploaded one, because I think it's a bit different.
Will post results as soon as I can.

Comment: Of course, don't worry about that. If it does work, I won't forget to thank you and mark your answert. I just want to make sure first.